# Where are the config files for Pidgin via Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, file, mdm

I installed [Pidgin](https://pidgin.im/) via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). I'm looking for config files such as `accounts.xml` and `prefs.xml`.

On Linux, I believe they're located in are in `~/.pidgin`, and `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Pidgin` on Windows.

I would expect them to be somewhere in `/usr/local/Cellar/pidgin`, but they're not, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All config files for pidgin reside in the (invisible) folder ~/.purple.

[image]